# BeautifulSoup4 can't be installed in python3.5 on Windows7

Tags: windows, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, installation, python-2to3

I have downloaded beautifulsoup4-4.5.3.tar.gz from https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download/4.5/ and unzipped it to my python work directory(which is **not** my python install directory).

However, when I run

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

in my IDLE the error massage popped out:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
File "D:\python\beautifulsoup4-4.5.3\beautifulsoup4-4.5.3\bs4\__init__.py", 
line 53
'You are trying to run the Python 2 version of Beautiful Soup under Python 
3. This will not work.'<>'You need to convert the code, either by installing 
it (`python setup.py install`) or by running 2to3 (`2to3 -w bs4`).'

 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried these methods but the error massage above keeps popping out

1. open setup.py in my IDLE and run it(gives `=== RESTART: D:\python\beautifulsoup4-4.5.3\beautifulsoup4-4.5.3\setup.py ===` in IDLE windows, but `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` didn't work)
2. use cmd and go to D:\python\beautifulsoup4-4.5.3\beautifulsoup4-4.5.3, run `pip uninstall beautifulsoup4` then run `pip install beautifulsoup4`;it shows that I have successfully installed beautifulsoup4-4.5.3 in cmd line, however, error massage still appearred in IDLE after `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`
3. use cmd and go to
   D:\python\beautifulsoup4-4.5.3\beautifulsoup4-4.5.3, run `pip3
   uninstall beautifulsoup4` then run `pip3 install beautifulsoup4`;
   useless as above
4. run `pip install bs4 --ignore-installed`,useless as above
5. run `setup.py install`,useless as above
6. run `2to3 -w bs4` in cmd line under D:\python\beautifulsoup4-4.5.3\beautifulsoup4-4.5.3, returns `'2to3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.`

what should I do?

beside,`pip show bs4` gives this

```
`Metadata-Version: 1.1
Name: bs4
Version: 0.0.1
Summary: Screen-scraping library
Home-page: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4
Author: Leonard Richardson
Author-email: leonardr@segfault.org
License: MIT
Location: c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-
32\lib\site-packages
Requires: beautifulsoup4
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' 
command.`
```

under my C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages directory, I can see three beautifulsoup related directories:beautifulsoup4-4.5.3.dist-info, bs4 and  bs4-0.0.1-py3.5.egg-info, but `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` keep throwing out wrong message

Comment: do you have 2 different python version installed in your pc?

Answer (score 2):

BeautifulSoup4 is compatible with Python 3x and 2x, but the installation process is a bit different. The following is how I installed it for Python 3x.

Go to http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/#Download or https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4/4.3.2 and download beautifulsoup4-4.3.2.tar.gz.

Navigate to the folder where you downloaded the file. Use 7zip to extract the beautifulsoup4-4.3.2.tar.gz  file.

Double click the beautifulsoup4-4.3.2.tar.gz folder to drill down though the dist folder and then extract the beautifulsoup4-4.3.2.tar file.

Double click the beautifulsoup4-4.3.2.tar folder to drill down through yet another beautifulsoup4-4.3.2 folder. Inside the beautifulsoup4-4.3.2 folder you will see the setup.py file.

Hold down the Shift key while right clicking anywhere inside the folder and select Open command window here.

At the command prompt type: setup.py install and press Enter.

When then installation stops running, verify that the package was installed by navigating to the C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages directory. If installed you will see the bs4 directory.

Verify that the installation is working by going to Go to Start > All Programs > Python 3.4 > IDLE (Python 3.4 GUI 32 bit) to launch the basic IDE.

After the prompt type: >>>from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

If you receive no errors it is working.

Comment: Followed the steps, I get` `Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
>>> `

Answer (score 1):

This problem solved in three steps:

First, delete all the beautifulsoup related directories and files under your python install directory, I mean **all** the beautifulsoup related directories under this C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages

second, run `pip uninstall beautifulsoup4` then `pip install beautifulsoup4` under D:\python\beautifulsoup4-4.5.3\beautifulsoup4-4.5.3 in cmd line, that is, where setup.py lies.

third, you need open setup.py in your IDLE and Run Module

finally, run `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` in main IDLE windows. No error message now.